# What is intermediate between a particular case citation and time immemorial?

Tags: common-law, legal-history, precedent

What is intermediate between a particular case citation and time immemorial?

Often, common law precedents are cited by the cases that established them replete with the exact year of the precedent case. Other concepts like "common law torts" or "common law marriage" were established after the dawn of common law, so not time immemorial, but when asked what their basis is, one seems unable to trace it to any particular decision but just "common law". Why are some of these untraceable and how do they come to have dedicated terms and names?

In another answer, one writes "Long-standing precedents whose origins are lost in the mists of time"

How can precedents be cited much less relied upon when they are "lost in the mists of time"?

Comment: This question seems quite clear.

Comment: Are you essentially responding to the close votes?

Comment: Yes, this comment was posted while going through the close queue. When someone give a close reason of "needs details or clarity" and I don't see any such lack on review,  I often post a comment such as this. It is intended to be considered by possible future close voters and reviewers.

Comment: Good work as always.